# Using conditional formatting to highlight a row if the date in the column F equals todays date

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

How would I get a row in my table to highlight if the date in the column F equals todays date.

[image]

Note that more than one row can be lit up at once.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**STEP 1:**

Select your table *without headers* (`B24:G31` in image below).

With selected table go to `HOME->CONDITIONAL FORMATTING->New Rule...`

[image]

**STEP 2:**

Select *`Use formula to determine which cells to format`*, enter formula: `=$F24=TODAY()`, choose desired formatting and press OK.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: You can also do that without formulas - select "Highlight Cell rules" and then "A date occuring" and select "today" from the dropdown

Comment: @barryhoudini, absolutelly true! however using this approach it would be a problem to highlight _entire row_ based on value in column `F`

Comment: OK, yes, for entire row you need the formula

Comment: Thanks @simoco! I don't know why Microsoft doesn't add a built-in rule to "highlight row or column based on the value of a cell". This seems like a really common usage.

Answer (score 0):

If column A is just months and you want to show the annual rows then use the below formula

=MOD($A1,12)=0

Don't forget to format you row